# Phone number formatting in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have so many numbers in so many format like `2123244559`, or `364 7890`, or `02246802121`.

I want to write them in the same format like `0 ### ### ## ##`, but the "format cell" tab isn't working.

I've tried different options to achieve that, but I couldn't. How can I write them in this format?

Comment: If you don't intend on using the numbers in calculations you could turn the cells to text cells. Formatting may then work... Give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatting is correct.  One possibility is that the phone number is stored as "Text" not numbers or "General".  Also, see if there is a small green triangle at top-left corner of the cell warning "Number stored as text".

You may also check the cell format: Click on the cell, go to "Home" > "Number" > "Number format" (i.e. the dropdown list") and make sure it is not "Text".  If so, change it to General and apply your format again.

Comment: I have one more question. Some numbers are like 90 342 230 65 56, some are like +90 212 295 23 85,some are 0090 216 967 23 12, and some are 0212 342 68 78. I want to write them with just one zero in front of them like " 0 212 342 34 43". Do you have any suggestion to me to make it done?

Comment: If you are doing an one-off conversion, you can use formula to convert everything into value.  Assume you keep your phone number in column A (A1:A200 for example), in cell B1 type the formula `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` and drag the formula from B1 to fill up to B200.  Then B1:B200 contains the phone numbers in number value.  Copy B1:B200 and then paste value (Home > Clipboard > Paste > Paste Value) to A1:A200 and then apply formatting if necessary.  You can then delete column B afterwards.

Comment: I've tried it but i don't know why, there are cells filled in with 9.02166E+11 , 9.03422E+11. i couldn't get how to write the formula for A1:A20 for exemple.

Comment: It's fine; once you apply the format again the 9.02166E+11 thing will become your telephone format.  By default, Excel shows big numbers in scientific notation (i.e. the 1.23E+11 notation).

Answer (score 0):

To insert spaces, use `\`  or `" "`.
For context, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/983064/287154) by [miroxlav](https://superuser.com/users/287473/miroxlav). Quoting:

> [Spaces have special meaning](https://superuser.com/a/983064/287154), they aren't plain spaces what you expect. To achieve insertion of standard spaces, escape space characters (make them literal) using `\` which makes standard character from special character following it. Or put them into double quotes.