# Inserting spaces into custom number format has no effect

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got several phone numbers that Excel displays as (for instance) :

`0147200001`

I want to display them as :

`01 47 20 00 01`

Using the Custom Format Number, I've entered `## ## ## ## ##`, but the numbers stays the same.

Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use format `00\ 00\ 00\ 00\ 00` (or if you prefer double quotes: `00" "00" "00" "00" "00`).

[Spaces have special meaning](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4), they aren't plain spaces what you expect. To achieve insertion of standard spaces, escape space characters (make them literal) using `\` which makes standard character from special character following it. Or put them into double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Useful question and accepted answer, thanks! It didn't bubble up in a Google search, though. To help with SEO and to add the specific Excel code for correct formatting of Norwegian mobile phone numbers, it should read `###" "##" "###`